# Usar unicode en Pydot

Tags: python, graphviz, pydot

estoy haciendo un grafico desde pydot y necesito insertar el caracter lambda λ pero me genera el error
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u03bb'

```
graph.add_edge(pydot.Edge("i","p",label="λ,λ;#"))
```

quisiera saber como codifico en formato unicode para poder generar el grafico

Comment: Hola Angel, ¿Versión de Python? ¿Codificación usada en tu script?

Comment: son 3.8.2 y ascii

Comment: Guarda el script usando UTF-8, acabo de probar por si había algún problema con pydot pero todo funciona como debe con 3.8.2 y UTF-8.

Comment: es decir el string ?

Comment: como puedo hacer eso disculpa

Comment: Eso depende del editor que uses, pero una cosa ¿Estás usando Windows?

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107034/discussion-between-angel-and-fjsevilla).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error parece aparecer al usar `pydot.Dot.write` o alguna de sus variantes. El problema es que internamente usa `open` y si no se especifica encoding `open` usa el encoding local (`locale.getpreferredencoding(False)`), que en Winodws generalmente no va a ser UTF-8.

La solución es pasar el encoding explícitamente a `write` que a su vez se lo pasa a `open`:

```
import pydot


graph = pydot.Dot(graph_type='graph')
graph.add_edge(pydot.Edge("i","p",label="λ,λ;#"))
```

---

```
graph.write_png("graph.png", encoding="utf-8")
```

---

```
graph.write("graph.png", format="png", encoding="utf-8")
```

---

```
graph.write_svg("graph.svg", encoding="utf-8")
```

Obviamente el encoding debe coincidir con el usado en el script.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]